# Straight lines - point of intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, graphing-functions

Question:
Two rays in the first quadrant:
$$x +y = |a|$$ 
$$ax - y = 1$$ 
intersect each other in the interval $a \in (a_0, \infty)$, the what is the value of $a_0$?

I don't even understand where to begin this question. I tried plotting a rough sketch of the lines by assuming a random value for $a$, but that didn't get me anywhere. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

We may suppose that $a\not =0$.

The line $x+y=|a|$ passes through two points $(0,|a|),(|a|,0)$. And the line $ax-y=1\iff y=ax-1$ passes through the point $(0,-1)$ with the slope $a$.

Since the two lines intersect in the first quadrant, the slope $a$ of the second line has to be larger than $a_0$ such that $y=a_0x-1$ passes through the point $(|a_0|,0)$. Hence we have
$$0=a_0|a_0|-1\iff a_0|a_0|=1.$$
If $a_0\gt 0$, then $(a_0)^2=1$ leads $a_0=1$.

If $a_0\lt 0$, then $-(a_0)^2=1$ has no real solution.

Therefore, we have $a_0=1$.

Comment: Hmmmm...... Did you like the question? :P On a more serious note, i don't understand where you said the slope $a$ of the second line has to be larger...... Like that whole sentence.

Comment: @Gummybears: Well, can you draw two lines on the $xy$ plane? Seeing the graphs helps a lot.

Comment: Why does it have to pass through that point? Cannot it have a steeper slope so it enters the first quadrant before the point $(|a_0|,0)$?

Comment: @Gummybears: Please note that $a_0\lt a$, not $a_0\le a$. Actually, $a_0$ is not included in $a$, right? and $a$ can be any real number larger than $a_0$.

Comment: I see. That makes sense now o.O

Comment: Well an awesome answer once again. Thanks!